# Display categories with child category separated by letter

Tags: categories

I'm trying to show both the parent and child categories of my custom post type separated by the first letter of the category

What I have.

```
A.
Apples

B. 
Bananas

C. 
Coconuts
```

What I want

```
A.
Apples<br />
-Red<br />
-Green<br />

B. 
Bananas

C. 
Coconuts
```

Here's the code I have now. I just need it to show the child categories too. Thanks in advanced.

```
<?php 
$list = '';
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => true,  // Set this to true to hide terms with no posts
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'pad_counts' => false 
);
$tags = get_terms('type',$args);
$groups = array(  );

if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
        $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
}
if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
    $index_line = '';
    foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
        $list .= '<h4><p id="' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '"><strong>'. apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) .'</strong></P></h4><hr><ul>';
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
        $list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $tag ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all posts tagged with %s', ''), $tag->name) . '">' . $tag->name . ' </a></li>';
  }
  $list .= '</ul>'; 
}
$list .= '';
}
} else $list .= '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';

print ($index_line);
print ($list);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to add another foreach loop, using the [get_term_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) function.

Change your lines:

```
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
    $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
    $list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $tag ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all posts tagged with %s', ''), $tag->name) . '">' . $tag->name . ' </a></li>';
}
```

...to...

```
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
    $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
    $list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $tag ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all posts tagged with %s', ''), $tag->name) . '">' . $tag->name . ' </a>';

    // show children in their own ul
    if($children = get_term_children($tag->ID, 'type')) {
        $list .= '<ul>';
        foreach($children as $child) {
            $list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all posts tagged with %s', ''), $child->name) . '">' . $tag->name . ' </a></li>';
        }
        $list .= '</ul>';
    }

    // close li after this one
    $list .= '</li>';
}
```

(untested)

You could make this method far more beautiful if you would do it recursive ;) But I think this should do.

Comment: Hmm, it isn't working. I think that there's some other issue going on.

Comment: does it throw an error or something? Ist "type" the taxonomy name, and is it hierarchical?